# Java AccessControlException: Access Denied when writing

Tags: java, exception, input, io, output

When reading a .csv file i have no problems. But at the end of the code when i'm trying to write a new value to it, I'm getting an access denied exception and i'm not entirely sure why. Can anyone explain what might be causing this?

```
private Path highScoreFile = Paths.get("/Applications/JavaFinalAssignment/highscore.csv");
public String checkhighScore()
{

try{
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(highScoreFile));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    String s = "";
    String delimiter = ",";
    s = reader.readLine();

    while(s!= null)
    {
        scoreArray = s.split(delimiter);    
        highScoreName = scoreArray[0];
        highScoreNum = Integer.parseInt(scoreArray[1]);         
        s = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e);
    }
    String scoreReturn = (scoreArray[0] + " " + scoreArray[1]);
    return scoreReturn;
}

public void setHighScore(String name, int num)
{
    try
    {
    String s = "";
    String delimiter = ",";
    OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(highScoreFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
    String numString = Integer.toString(num);
    s = name + delimiter + numString;
    writer.write(s);
    writer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error saving high score file: " + e);
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Stack trace added:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Users/Matt/Desktop/JavaFinalAssignment/highscore.csv" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.open(UnixChannelFactory.java:240)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.newFileChannel(UnixChannelFactory.java:138)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixChannelFactory.newFileChannel(UnixChannelFactory.java:150)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:211)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
at FinalAssignment.setHighScore(FinalAssignment.java:335)
at FinalAssignment.GameOver(FinalAssignment.java:239)
at FinalAssignment.actionPerformed(FinalAssignment.java:140)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: Generally users cannot write to `/Applications`. Can you try a different location?

Comment: Do you have writting permissions of the file?

Comment: @hexafraction If i move it to the desktop, same problem.

Comment: Look at (and post) the stack trace.  This often contains the root cause.

Comment: Can you write in the file with ``setHighScore`` if you dont execute ``checkhighScore()`` before?

Comment: @Evans no, i still get the same error

Comment: @EJK How would i do this? sorry still pretty new at Java

Comment: In your catch block, right after the "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e);" line, put the following:  e.printStackTrace().  This will write the stack trace to the console window.  [Or it may already exist in the Message Dialog].

Answer (score 1):

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Users/Matt/Desktop/JavaFinalAssignment/highscore.csv" "write"

This isn't an operating-system user permissions issue, it is a Java sandbox permissions issue. You are running under a security manager and your .policy file doesn't grant you write permission to that directory. Either remove the security manager, or maybe sign the application, or adjust your .policy file. Whenever you get a `java.security.AccessControlException` it means you don't have the permission named in the message, in this case `java.io.FilePermission` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance but i'm not sure how to continue with this. Where would i find a .policy file?

Comment: The real question is why the SecurityManager? Is this an applet? an RMI client? a JWS application?